# Segmentation Fault 11 whenever I run this. Would like assistance/feedback

Tags: c++, fault

So I'm making a really rudimentary implementation of a circular list. I haven't made the remove function yet. Whenever I run the cpp, I get a seg fault 11. Any feedback would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    node* next=NULL;
    bool tail= false;
    int contents;
};
node* start;//start is a pointer that exists at the start of the list before the first element

class CircList{
node *seek;
public:

CircList (){  //creates a list of one node that points to itself
    node *b= new node;
        b->contents=0;
        b->next = b;
        start->next=b;
        b->tail=true;
}

bool empty(){
    if(start->next==NULL){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int size(CircList a){
    if(start->next==NULL){
        cout<<"size is 0 \n";
        return true;
    }
    seek=start->next;
    for(int i=0; i++;){
    if(seek->tail==true){
        cout<<"size is "<<i;
    }
    seek=seek->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void insert(int pos, int val){
    if(start->next ==NULL){//if inseting when the list is empty
        node *b= new node;
        b->next = b;
        b->tail=true;
        return;
    }

    node *b= new node;
    b->contents= val;
        seek=start->next;
    for(int i=0;i<=pos; i++){
        if(seek->tail==true){//if inserting at the end
            seek->tail=false;
            b->tail=true;
            seek->next=b;
            b->next=start->next;
        }
        if(pos==i){//if inserting between two nodes
            b->next = seek->next;
            seek->next = b;
        }
            seek=seek->next;
    }
    }
void remove(int a){
    seek=start->next;
     for(int i=0;i<=a-1; i++){
        if(i<a){
            seek=seek->next;
        }
        if(i==a-1){

}
     }
}

    void display(){
        cout<<start->next->contents; //will also be completed in the near future
        seek=start->next;
        for(int i=0; ;i++){
        if(seek->tail==false){
           cout<<seek->contents<<"\n";
        }
        if(seek->tail==true){
           cout<<seek->contents<<"\n";
           return;
        }
    }
        }
    };
```

That was the .h file. The following is the cpp. I just plugged in numbers to test. I want to get the program running so that I can test how it behaves.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CircList.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

CircList a;
a.insert (5,5);
a.insert (5,5);
a.insert (1,4);
a.insert (20,65);
a.insert (3,7);
a.size(a);
a.display();
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -g`), perhaps even with `-fsanitize=address` if available. Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Your question is off-topic, since you don't some any partial understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

I kept treating start as a node instead of a pointer. By making start = Null and replacing all the "start->next"'s with "start", I got it to compile and run. But now it's only infinitely inserting nodes with a value of 0 in the contents.

Edit: I fixed it. By changing that weird for loop in the display function to a while loop, it doesn't do infinite inserts of the node in the constructor, anymore. It seems to work decently enough now.

Answer (score 0):

This here causes a seg fault

```
start->next=b;
```

because start is NULL at the start of the program so you are de-referencing a null pointer.

instead set start to the first node in your constructor

```
start = b;
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes, once he fixes the seg bug i meant, but ok i will remove that.

Answer (score -1):

Your global variable `start` is an uninitialized pointer, yet you dereference it all over the place.

Comment: Thank you. I made the pointer NULL and it still compiles, but I still get the same seg fault when I run the code. Is there anything else I could do better?

Comment: @Sid dereferencing NULL is about as bad as using an uninitialized pointer. How did you write this much code without basic pointer understanding?

Comment: @Beta global variables without explicit initializer are value-initialized (in the case of pointers, this means a null pointer).